# Why can't I Call ContextRegisty.GetContext() in my singleton factory class 'Springfactory‘?

Tags: asp.net, spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container, spring.net

My Singleton factory class is defined like this:

```
 public sealed class SpringFactory
        {
            private static readonly Object ContainerLock=new object();
            private static IApplicationContext _applicationContext;
           // private SpringFactory(){}

            static SpringFactory()
            {
                lock (ContainerLock)
                {
                    _applicationContext = ContextRegistry.GetContext();           }
            }

            public static Object GetObject(string objectId)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (_applicationContext == null)
                    {
                        lock (ContainerLock)
                        {
                            _applicationContext = ContextRegistry.GetContext(); 
                        }     
                    } 
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    LogHelper.WriteLog(string.Format("SpringFactory.GetObject({0})",objectId), ex);
                }
                return _applicationContext.GetObject(objectId);
            }
        }
```

but if I initial spring IOC container by the call of  Springfactory.getObject(string name)
,a exception will be occured.en ,the exception log is :

```
time：2013-11-04 09:49:20,500 [1] 
level：ERROR 
type：logerror [(null)] 
SpringFactory.GetObject(adminFacade) 
 System.InvalidOperationException: root context is currently in creation. You must not call ContextRegistry.GetContext() from e.g. constructors of your singleton objects
   at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.InitializeContextIfNeeded()
   at Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext()
   at Domain.common.SpringFactory.GetObject(String objectId) in E:\CommercialProjects\huatongMISNew\huatongmis\HuaTongBusinessWeb\Domain\common\SpringFactory.cs:line 50
```

from the log ,it says that i must not call `ContextRegistry.GetContext()` in my Singleton factory class `SpringFactory`. But I don't know why.

Look for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove from your constructor the call to the context.

```
private IApplicationContext ApplicationContext
{
    lock (ContainerLock)
    {
        _applicationContext = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
    }
    return _applicationContext;
}

static SpringFactory()
{
}

// Some other code
```

As the exception says:

**root context is currently in creation. You must not call ContextRegistry.GetContext()**

You can't call a reference from the context or context itsef until creation is done.